# Can not connect to websocket server using WebSocket4Net

Tags: websocket, wss, mochiweb, websocket4net

I have a mochiweb as WebSocket server; connectivity using JavaScript from **Chrome** browser as ws client went smooth (open, send message, close). However, when I tried to connect from C# using **websocket4Net**, I always get below error from **mochiweb**.

> =CRASH REPORT==== 30-Jan-2013::16:57:41 ===
>     crasher:
>       initial call: mochiweb_acceptor:init/3
>       pid: <0.228.0>
>       registered_name: []
>       exception error: no case clause matching {error,timeout}
>         in function  mochiweb_http:websocket_init_with_origin_validated/4 (mochiweb_http.erl, line 292)
>         in call from mochiweb_http:headers_ws_upgrade/4 (mochiweb_http.erl, line 192)
>       ancestors: [cim_https,<0.166.0>]
>       messages: []
>       links: [<0.167.0>]
>       dictionary: []
>       trap_exit: false
>       status: running
>       heap_size: 1597
>       stack_size: 24
>       reductions: 1585

my C# snippet:

> ```
>         webSocketClient = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8080/login");
>                     webSocketClient.Error += new EventHandler<SuperSocket.ClientEngine.ErrorEventArgs>(webSocketClient_Error) ;
>         webSocketClient.AllowUnstrustedCertificate = true;
>         webSocketClient.Opened += new EventHandler(webSocketClient_Opened);
>         webSocketClient.Closed += new EventHandler(webSocketClient_Closed);
>         webSocketClient.MessageReceived += new EventHandler<MessageReceivedEventArgs>(webSocketClient_MessageReceived);
>         webSocketClient.Open();
> ```

Is there any parameter that I've missed ? Any idea on how to trace this ?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. Apparently, Mochiweb only supports what in websocket4net is known as Hybi00 -no support for RFC 6455 yet.
Seems like now I have to patch my mochiweb.